# Deploy Android on AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I want to create a host with android operation system on amazon web services. Is it possible to implement or not? I tried this to do on esx in my local environment  with android lollipop iso image and it was implemented. So is there any way to create a host on aws using an iso file?

Comment: I have no idea if it's technically possible, just want to know why you would want to do this

Comment: "your own ios file"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [Ravello Systems](https://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/android-emulator-on-amazon-ec2-and-google-cloud/) for running (emulated) Android on AWS EC2.

Comment: And to how to deploy ESX on aws?

Comment: You can't "deploy" ESX on AWS. AWS offers the ability to import AMIs from vCenter (See https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/), but this will undoubtly do you no good for an Android image. You'll need to follow the Ravello Systems tutorial to run an emulated version of Android which will be capable of running your code. It's probably more hassle than it's worth.